# How to help neuronal network with an other model

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, transfer-learning

I am working on an image classification problem, the input data normally is images to classify, but I thought latitude and longitude would play something on these satellite images. I sorted by latitude, but I could sort by x and y coordinates and applied an LSTM model, that proved coordinates has an influence on target.

How to add this as a neural network (LSTM) to the more important image classification neural network. Any hint or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't figure out your question completely but you may want something like [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/31394/28175).

Comment: Check kaggle competitions for more ideas :) if I got you questions l correctly, you must train your CNN to output two things then... One the probability and secondly the latitude and the longitude it thinks the image is from maybe

Comment: @Aditya you didn't get my question, latitude and longitude are features among image data, orientation is the target.

Comment: Yep! I forwarded your question to get help! Will update if someone shares anything that can help you!

Comment: @Aditya Media's suggestion seems the right one, I will be back with something . ty